# How to stop image from scaling when screen size changes

Tags: css, image, scaling

Right now my wordpress site is set up so the images scale when the screen size changes. I was hoping that, instead, the image can remain at a specific size in the center of the screen and become cropped equally on the left and right when the screen size changes.

I have tried max-width:none but that doesn't keep and crop the image in the center of the page.

Site: Zxndesignco.com

The image in question is the only image on the home page. I only know CSS so I was hoping there is a CSS solution.

Example of what i'm taking about: https://gatewaydemo.wordpress.com/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to not use an image, and make that image the `background-image` of that hero section instead. So delete the `img` tag and add something like this CSS to `.sow-image-container` `height: 400px; background: url(https://zxndesignco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/HomeImg.jpg) center top; background-size: cover`

Comment: ha ha I was getting there But yeah that is the way to do it.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks. That worked perfectly! Only problem is I don't want that image to appear on any other page other then the home page. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @BL91  then target `.home .sow-image-container` instead.

Comment: Wow, awesome!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center fixed;
 background-image:url(https://zxndesignco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/HomeImg.jpg);
 background-attachment:fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  }
.white{
   font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="white">Here are some words</p>
  </div>
```

Usually in the body or in a `div`. I like this group because it covers all the browser bases.